# Remove a field from a struct, transform a struct

Tags: go

From the Google Drive API I get a struct [type File](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/drive/v3#File). This struct is almost the same as the struct I would like to insert into BigQuery.

The File struct contains an "AppProperties" field that is incompatible with BigQuery:

```
AppProperties map[string]string `json:"appProperties,omitempty"`
```

So the end result that I would like to have is the same struct, with the AppProperties field removed. So basically the question is "how to remove a field from a struct" but that does not make sense as the struct values are mutable, but the struct fields are not. At least that is what I understand now.

The only solution I can think of is, copy the File struct definition and omit the AppProperties field and move all the field values over.

What would be the right way to do this in Go?

Comment: If your issue comes with the handling of `MarshalJSON`, Instead of redefining, you could copy the variable holding the struct over and set it's `AppProperties` to `nil`.

Comment: Thanks John. You mean converting it to JSON and back to a struct? In that case I still need to define my own struct without the AppPropereties field. That will work, however it feels like a lot of effort just to  remove a field.

Comment: I mean, if you just want to insert it into BigQuery, and you insert it as JSON, the method I described should work for that use case assuming you don't want to read back. Otherwise yeah most likely a different struct is the way as they (conceptually) should be different types.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes that makes sense, writing JSON to BigQuery will work. About the different struct, apart from embedding another struct in a struct, there is no  to reuse parts of another struct? I can copy paste the File struct

Comment: Yeah, aside from embedding there's not a way to copy over the struct definition as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to copy struct and omit needless field for you, it's tedious but there is no other way...