# Streaming JSON into Bigquery

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-drive-api

From the Google Drive API I receive an array of [Structs type File](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/drive/v3#File). My aim is to add a few fields and stream the data into BigQuery.

My first approach was to [change the File Struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329591/remove-a-field-from-a-struct-transform-a-struct) and stream the updated Structs to BigQuery. This looks like a dead end and I am trying to use the suggested method, Marshall the Struct into JSON and stream that into BigQuery.

I found this example [bigquery-table-insert-rows](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows), but that implements the ValueSaver interface. For me a simple Marshall and then stream the JSON to BigQuery should be enough.

However, I can't find any method or example that does that. So I would like to know if it is possible, stream JSON into BigQuery using Go. An basic example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track in thinking that just providing the structs is enough.

Maybe looking at some simple but complete code will be of some help: https://github.com/tovare/idporten

All I do is put a slice of structs, where the structs are annotated with BigQuery.

```
type Metric struct {
    Timestamp time.Time `bigquery:"timestamp"`
    Metode    string    `bigquery:"metode"`
    Antall    int       `bigquery:"antall"`
}
```

....

```
seriesTableRef := client.Dataset(datasetName).Table(tableName)
    if err := seriesTableRef.Inserter().Put(ctx, metrics); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Comment: The Structs I receive from the Drive API are incompatible with BigQuery, there is a map field in the Struct. So I can't insert them directly into BigQuery.